# How to avoid TextView resizing in GridLayout v7?

Tags: android, textview, android-gridlayout

I want to create a 3x3 grid using GridLayout v7. In my code, the cell of TextView automatically resize according to it's content. Furthermore, it affect the size of other cells, although they sit on 2 different rows.

Here's a sample code with 2x2 grid. The TextView sit atop, spanning 2 columns. Each button should occupy half the available screen (1 column). How can I fix the size of the TextView, and other components? Thanks!

Of course I can try a nested LinearLayout but that's not a recommended practice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:text="How to make this box stop growing while adding some text to it?"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
        grid:layout_rowSpan="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="some button"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_columnSpan="1"
        grid:layout_rowSpan="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="some button"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_columnSpan="1"
        grid:layout_rowSpan="1"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set layout_height and layout_width.
Just like below.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

android support some options "match_parent" or "wrap_content".

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: No, your solution doesn't fix my problem :( and I think it doesn't make sense   at all. What I'm trying to do is distributing space by percent, so match_parent will stretch everything to the GridLayout. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="How to make this box stop growing while adding some text to it?"
        grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill"/>

    <Button
        android:text="some button"/>

    <Button
        android:text="some button"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```